# How to make the slack app appear in iOS search?

Tags: search, iphone, ios, slack

How do I make the slack app appear when I search for it in my iPhone?  As you can see in the screenshots, the Gmail and Spotify apps have no such problem -- how do I make slack behave the same?

/YGA

[image: iOS screenshot]

[image: iOS screenshot]

[image: iOS screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Siri > Search and find Slack under Apps.  Turn on Show App in Search.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same thing before. Whenever this happens, you will need to power your phone off, then back on again.

- Press Volume Up
- Press Volume Down
- Then hold the power button on the right
- You'll see the option now to swipe to power your device off
- After 20ish seconds, you can hold that power button again to turn your iPhone back on.

Comment: A simpler way to reboot your phone would be to go to settings > general > shut down (at the very bottom)